# If statement is still running code even when condition is false

Tags: python

The program is supposed to loop through a 2d list and if a random number is less than the percentage chance that an enemy can spawn in the room, then the index the loop is on is assigned to an enemy. The code is not supposed to run when x and y are equal to the starting position of the player but the code runs anyway even when the condition is false

```
import random, os
while True:
  os.system('clear')
  map = [
    ['#', '-', '+', '-', '%'],
    ['+', '#', '|', '#', '+'],
    ['+', '-', '%', '-', '#'],
    ['|', '#', '+', '#', '+'],
    ['+', '%', '-', '+', '+']
  ]
  startPlayerX = round(len(map[0])/2)
  startPlayerY = round(len(map)/2)
  monsterMap = [[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
  for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
      if x != startPlayerX and y != startPlayerY:
        monsterChance = random.randint(1, 100)
        if map[x][y] == '#':
          if monsterChance <= 49:
            monsterMap[x][y] = '&'
          elif monsterChance > 49 and monsterChance <= 70:
            monsterMap[x][y] = '@'
        elif map[x][y] == '%':
          if monsterChance < 35:
            monsterMap[x][y] = '&'
          elif monsterChance > 35 and monsterChance <= 50:
            monsterMap[x][y] = '@'
  break
for x in range(5):
  for y in range(5):
    print(monsterMap[x][y], ' ', end = '')
  print()
```

Comment: If the code is running then the condition **is not false**. You need to figure out why the condition is true when you think it shouldn't be. Also please see [mcve].

Comment: Do integer division. `startPlayerX = len(map[0])//2` and `startPlayerY = len(map)//2`.  Also note that your use of X and Y in those statements is backwards from your use of X and Y elsewhere.  What you really want throughout here is `map[y][x]`, so `y` represents the row number, and `x` represents the column.

Comment: _but the code runs anyway even when the condition is false_ What is the code doing that makes you think this?  Is there some specific output that the code produces, that you didn't expect to see?

Comment: nevermind I just forgot that indices start at 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that you're using the `and` operator in the if condition to check if both `x` and `y` are not equal to the starting position. This means that if either `x` or `y` is equal to the starting position, the condition will still be true. To fix this, you should use the `or` operator instead, so the code won't run if either `x` or `y` equals the starting position.

Change this line:

`if x != startPlayerX and y != startPlayerY:`

to:

`if x != startPlayerX or y != startPlayerY:`

Comment: Maybe simpler: `if (x, y) != ...:`